# Silverlight and Java end of life in various browsers

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, silverlight, firefox

Google have taken the first step to remove Silverlight and Java applet support in Chrome: 
http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html

Does anyone know if Internet Explorer and Firefox are on the same path? For how long will Silverlight and Java applets continue to work in those browsers (on PC)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Firefox, but MS does not support Silverlight in Spartan as of the current preview build but will continue supporting the plugin in IE 11 desktop mode.  The end of life support on Silverlight is dated on 10/12/2021 for V5 - [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=Silverlight&Filter=FilterNO)